# Connect to MSSQL via ODBC with FreeTDS

Tags: freetds, unixodbc

I am working with a group who needs to access a MSSQL db from a linux host and in my searching found FreeTDS, which i am able to connect with FreeTDS but our programmer states that ODBC will require to configured with FreeTDS for their PHP code to work. With that being said, i have tried configuring both unixODBC and unixODBC_23 for the past day and have been unsuccesful in finding a config that works properly and I am also not able to get tracing working either. So, without further ado, here is my config

--- odbc.ini and odbc_23.ini ---

```
[TC]
Description = FreeTDS Connection
Driver = FreeTDS
Database = mydb
ServerName = 192.168.1.12
TDS_Version = 7.0
PORT = 3433
[Default]
Driver          = /usr/local/freetds-0.91/lib/libtdsodbc.so
```

---odbcinst.ini and odbcinst_23.ini---

```
[FreeTDS]
Description = FreeTDS
Driver = /usr/local/freetds-0.91/lib/libtdsodbc.so
Trace = 1
TraceFile = /tmp/freetds.log
UsageCount = 1
```

When i try connecting via isql, here is what i receive.

```
root@host(~)# isql_23 -v TC myuser mydb
[S1000][unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unable to connect to data source
[01000][unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unknown host machine name.
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect
root@host(~)#
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Try Server instead of ServerName?

```
  Server = 192.168.1.12
```

Comment: That seems to have helped! Now im connecting but my credentials are failing. Pretty sure i can figure out the rest. Thanks so much for pointing that out Philippe!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so there was one additional change that i had to make in addition to changing "ServerName" to "Server" and that was I removed "Database = mydb" and moved it to the "Server" and now my file looks like so:

```
[TC]
Description = FreeTDS
Driver = FreeTDS
Server = 192.168.1.12\mydb
TDS_Version = 7.0
PORT = 3433
```

and now im connected with this command:

```
root@host(~)# isql_23 -v TC user password
+---------------------------------------+
| Connected!                            |
|                                       |
| sql-statement                         |
| help [tablename]                      |
| quit                                  |
|                                       |
+---------------------------------------+
SQL> ^C
root@host(~)#
```